# Testing a Rails form_tag in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I cannot simulate my form_tag in Rspec. The form_tag will package the parameter hash as a simple hash while the Rspec will package as a hash of hashes with the parameters, in this case, inside of :session hash like:

> {"session"=>{"email"=>"billy@example.com", "password"=>"foobar"}, "controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"create"}

vs Rails form_tag:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AiurjCANkzCJFl+oiJK2tQVzzxrET260bo1wxuDHB74=", "email"=>"billy@example.com", "password"=>"foobar", "commit"=>"Sign in", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sessions"}

The Sessions controller is using:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

to extract the email parameter. This will work for the development but for the Rspec test I would have to use:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
```

Here is my latest Rspec test:

```
describe "success" do
before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @attr = {:email => @user.email, :password => @user.password }
end

it "should redirect to the user show page" do
  #post :create, :session =>   @attr #same results
  post sessions_path(:email => @user.email, :password => @user.password)
  response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.full_name)
end
end
```

This will fail because of the difference in the parameter hashes above. Is there a way in Rspec to send parameters to the session controller in a single hash to match the form_tag as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the parameters manually in your tests

```
describe "success" do
before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @attr = {:email => @user.email, :password => @user.password }
end

it "should redirect to the user show page" do
  post :create, :email => @user.email, :password => @user.password
  response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.full_name)
end
end
```

This will send the parameters to your method in the controller as

{... "email"=>"billy@example.com", "password"=>"foobar" ...}